# Is this inequality $\frac{1}{k^2} \ge \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(k+2)^2} + \cdots $ true?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Is this inequality $\frac{1}{k^2} \ge \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(k+2)^2} + \cdots $ true for $k \in \mathbb{N}$? I am proving the strong law of large number, and I come across this inequality. I think that this inequality is true, but I am not sure how to prove this. I would appreciate if you give me some help.

Comment: It does not seem very plausible for large $k$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{25}<\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{49}$.

Comment: $1/4^2 + 1/5^2 + 1/6^2 > 1/3^2$

Comment: My -1 because you don't seem to have really looked at the inequality, which is virtually never true.

Answer (score 3):

Your assertion is equivalent to

$$1 \ge \frac {k^2} {(k+1)^2} + \frac {k^2} {(k+2)^2} + \dots$$

But, for large $k$, you can make arbitrarily many summands on the right-hand side as close to $1$ as you want. Hence, you can make the expression on the right-hand side as large as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, and it's easy to just check numerically. It is well known that
$$S=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 \approx 0.645$$
However $S-\frac{1}{2^2} \approx 0.395 > \frac{1}{2^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Seems obvious that

$$\frac1{(k+1)^2}+\frac1{(k+2)^2}\approx\frac2{k^2}$$ and the inequality has chances to be violated.

Indeed this occurs with $k=4$ and all values above !

---

In fact , the inequality is only true for $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact
$$\eqalign{\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(k+2)^2} + \ldots &> \dfrac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} + \dfrac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)} + \ldots\cr
& = \dfrac{1}{k+1} - \dfrac{1}{k+2} + \dfrac{1}{k+2} - \dfrac{1}{k+3} + \ldots\cr
& = \dfrac{1}{k+1}} $$
and $1/(k+1) > 1/k^2$ if $k \ge 2$.